# A simple differentiation question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> By introducing a new variable t, putting $x=\cos t$, the expression $(1-x^2)\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+y$ is transformed into...(meaning there should no variable x in the differential expression, only in terms of y & t)

What I tried:
$$t=\cos^{-1}x \implies \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
From here I tried squaring and differentiating again. I don't get a correct answer. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say $x = \cos t \implies dx = -\sin t\ dt$. Also,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = -\frac{1}{\sin t} \frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left( -\frac{1}{\sin t} \frac{dy}{dt}\right) \frac{dt}{dx} \\
= \left( \frac{\cot t}{\sin t}\frac{dy}{dt} - \frac{1}{\sin t} \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \right)\left(-\frac{1}{\sin t}\right)$$

After this, it's a matter of substituting in the original expression to get:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \cot t \frac{dy}{dt} + \cot t \frac{dy}{dt} + y$$
Cancel the terms in the middle to give
$$\boxed{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + y}$$

Answer (score 0):

$dx = d\cos t = -\sin t dt$

$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{-1}{\sin t}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{-1}{\sin t}$

$\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})$

$\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{-1}{\sin t}\frac{d}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} = \frac{-1}{\sin t}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{-1}{\sin t}\frac{dy}{dt}) = -\frac{\cos t}{\sin^3t }\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{\sin^2 t}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$